Get User Pool App Client Name from AWS Cognito user pool in Spring boot REST API
I have a springboot API (with out user login) which uses AWS cognito to authorize the application. I need to get the user pool app client name along with the client id as part of the bearer token. I am bringing in the bearer token and decoding it with jwt decoder to see if its present. I don't see application clients Name as part of the paylaod. My question is, is it possible to get the client name along with client id? If so how? any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Prasanna
